# Is there a way to solve the BuildContext problem?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: Error Image]

I'm getting The argument type `BuildContext Function()` can't be assigned to the parameter type `BuildContext`.

Comment: what is myString?

Comment: just a variable

Comment: Do you have `BuildContext context()` in your state class defined?

Comment: no i do not have

Answer (score 0):

You can't send context to a function when it isn't even defined in the initstate function. Here you are trying to use provider outside the Build Function which is a no no. What you can do as an alternative is to wrap the function with a Future to give it a valid context :

```
 WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
   myString = Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false).testString;
    });
```

Comment: You can use provider in the `initState` with `listen: false`. And `context` is a getter of `State` of a `StatefulWidget`

Comment: Well you can technically use it normally but that's not the ethical way to use it, it can cause future troubles in multiple cases.

Comment: `listen: false` was made to be able to call `Provider.of(context)` outside the build. What kind of troubles and cases are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing the flutter whole folder where it is saved and than remove the Environmental Values and remove path and add new download new Flutter SDK and than again update the path in  Environmental Values